# How do I get all items with which a user was in contact?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has two columns `userid` and `itemid`. I would like to select an `itemid` (for example 715) and get all users who had this `itemid`. I not only want the users but also all other items that the user has used at the same time. (An example is given below).
I have now used `isin` with the method, it only returns true and false.

How do I manage to get all the items that the user had who had this particular itemid?

```
d = {'userid': [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4],
     'itemid': [715, 845, 98, 12324, 85, 715, 2112, 85, 2112, 852, 102]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)

df2 = df.isin({'itemid': [715]})
print(df2)

    userid  itemid
0        0     715
1        0     845
2        0      98
3        1   12324
4        2      85
5        2     715
6        3    2112
7        3      85
8        4    2112
9        4     852
10       4     102
    userid  itemid
0    False    True
1    False   False
2    False   False
3    False   False
4    False   False
5    False    True
6    False   False
7    False   False
8    False   False
9    False   False
10   False   False
```

What I want

```
    userid  itemid
0        0     715
1        0     845
2        0      98
4        2      85
5        2     715
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In just ONE line of code.

Data:

```
d = {'userid': [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4],
     'itemid': [715, 845, 98, 12324, 85, 715, 2112, 85, 2112, 852, 102]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

df.head(7): # first 7 rows

```
   userid  itemid
0       0     715
1       0     845
2       0      98
3       1   12324
4       2      85
5       2     715
6       3    2112
```

```
df[df.userid.isin(df[df.itemid==715].userid)]
```

```
   userid  itemid
0       0     715
1       0     845
2       0      98
4       2      85
5       2     715
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `isin` twice - First to get users associated with `715`, the second `isin` is to filter for those users:

```
users = df.loc[df.itemid == 715, "userid"]
df.loc[df.userid.isin(users)]

    userid  itemid
0   0   715
1   0   845
2   0   98
4   2   85
5   2   715
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked. I wish you a great day.

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
In [450]: x = df[df.itemid.eq(715)].userid.unique()
In [452]: df[df.userid.isin(x)]
Out[452]: 
   userid  itemid
0       0     715
1       0     845
2       0      98
4       2      85
5       2     715
```